# Getting AppDelegate window nil in UnitTesting

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing

I m testing a method defined in AppDelegate. That method is accessing the window object but getting nil when call from unit test.
Below is the code.

```
class AppDelegateTests: XCTestCase {
var subject: AppDelegate!

override func setUp() {
    super.setUp()
    subject = AppDelegate()
}

func testPauseAppLaunch() {
    subject.pauseAppLaunch()
    print(subject.window?)
}
```

}

AppDelegate code is below. didFinishLaunch method is getting call correctly.

```
 #if DEBUG
/// Are unit tests running?
///
/// When the app is starting up in order to run the test suite, it can be helpful to short
/// circuit the normal app spin up. This helps inform that decision.
var isRunningTests: Bool {
    return NSClassFromString("XCTest") != nil
}
#endif

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
    Appearance.set()

    let window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    window.backgroundColor = .white
    self.window = window

    #if DEBUG
    guard !isRunningTests else {
        window.rootViewController = UIViewController()
        window.makeKeyAndVisible()
        return true
    }
    #endif
}

 func pauseAppLaunch() {
    FileLogger.default.log(message: "Pausing App Launch")
    let splashScreenStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "LaunchScreen", bundle: nil)
    let splashViewController = splashScreenStoryboard.instantiateInitialViewController()
    self.window?.rootViewController = splashViewController
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
}
```

In testAppLaunch method I m getting window as nil. Even in pauseAppLaunch method self.window is nil.
When I m debugging it Control is going in else part of guard. Window object is available there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use

```
subject = AppDelegate()
```

this will create a *new* instance of your AppDelegate, which has not run through the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` call.

Instead, use

```
subject = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
```

to access the correct one.